# Updating a column after new values is added in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having some troubles creating a trigger which will get the current point a person have, check to see what award he will be under, then update his reward title. So this is the scenario:

```
     PersonTable
    | Person (PK) | RewardTitle (FK) | Score|
    | A           | Beginner         | 0    |
    | B           | MidRange         | 17   |
    | C           | Professional     | 32   |

     RewardTable
    | RewardTitle (PK) | BottomScore | UpperScore| Reward        |
    | Beginner         | 0           | 9         | Free food     |
    | MidRange         | 10          | 19        | Free games    |
    | Professional     | 20          | 100       | Unlimited time|
```

The situation is, I want to update Person A so that he nows have 11 points then find out which RewardTitle does his new point belong to, and change his RewardTitle accordingly, so since he has 11 points, his RewardTitle will now be MidRange.

I attempted to create a trigger which tries to find the RewardTitle he belongs to then update this value accordingly, but I kept on getting an error saying:

```
    Person is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

and I understant the problem, but I cannot think of any other ways to achieve the result. I have tried using

```
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
```

but it still did not work, here is my attempt below:

```
    UPDATE PersonTable
    SET Score = 11
    WHERE Person = 'A';

    DELIMITER //
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER person_upd_trigger
    AFTER UPDATE ON PersonTable
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        temp_variable VARCHAR(120);
    BEGIN
        SELECT r.RewardTitle INTO temp_variable
        FROM PersonTable p, RewardTable r
        WHERE :NEW.Person = p.Person
        AND p.Score BETWEEN r.BottomScore AND r.UpperScore;

        UPDATE PersonTable
        SET RewardTitle = temp_variable
        WHERE :NEW.Person = Person;
   END;
```

I will be very grateful for all the help I could get, I am quite new to Oracle SQL. Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update the same table you are already updating in a BEFORE TRIGGER (if supposedly allowed would cause an infinite loop). Instead, you need to re-write your trigger as:

In order to this to work you should change your trigger definition to `BEFORE`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER person_upd_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON PersonTable -- declare it as BEFORE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    temp_variable VARCHAR(120);
BEGIN
    SELECT r.RewardTitle INTO temp_variable
    FROM RewardTable r
    WHERE :NEW.Score BETWEEN r.BottomScore AND r.UpperScore;

    -- here you are setting the new value, no need for an update.
    :NEW.RewardTitle := temp_variable;
END;
```

Comment: Hi Jorge thankyou for the response, I have tried to change my trigger according to what you have suggested, however when executing it's giving me a 'cannot change NEW values for this trigger type'?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that you trigger is a AFTER. I will change the answer.

Comment: Thankyou so much Jorge, you've been a great help, it works now.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)